# Percentage of total scholarly literature available in open access repositories by year of publication broken down by discipline

Tags: reference-request, open-access

I am looking for the percentage of total scholarly literature available in open access repositories by year of publication broken down by discipline.

I am aware of the following figure, however it is old. Are there any more recent statistics?

Swan, Alma. [Policy guidelines for the development and promotion of open access](https://books.google.com/books?id=ptsR-DIXX-AC&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=Percentage+of+total+scholarly+literature+available+in+open+access+repositories+by+year+of+publication+broken+down+by+discipline&source=bl&ots=4Bl_7XTuwm&sig=ygB4srJqK6zwYBWnIeSYbltR5rk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU26jb9dfOAhWEVh4KHRiaBY8Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=Percentage%20of%20total%20scholarly%20literature%20available%20in%20open%20access%20repositories%20by%20year%20of%20publication%20broken%20down%20by%20discipline&f=false). UNESCO, 2012.

[image]

Comment: Presumably this is a [tag:reference-request]? Unless you are also interested in speculation.

Comment: @ff524 Good point, let's avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see, to answer this question based upon a more recent data set one has to create the needed data set in advance.

An overview [article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/asi.22963) ([open access version](http://www.openaccesspublishing.org/apc8/Personal%20VersionGreenOa.pdf)) published in 2013 is the most recent work I could find. Even an [article](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/75685/percentage-of-total-scholarly-literature-available-in-open-access-repositories-b) from 2016 analyses only articles published between 2010 and 2012.

Unfortunately, neither the data set behind the [shown picture](http://www.informationr.net/ir/21-2/paper712.html) nor the method used to create the data set is given in the [report](https://books.google.com/books?id=ptsR-DIXX-AC&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=Percentage+of+total+scholarly+literature+available+in+open+access+repositories+by+year+of+publication+broken+down+by+discipline&source=bl&ots=4Bl_7XTuwm&sig=ygB4srJqK6zwYBWnIeSYbltR5rk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU26jb9dfOAhWEVh4KHRiaBY8Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=Percentage%20of%20total%20scholarly%20literature%20available%20in%20open%20access%20repositories%20by%20year%20of%20publication%20broken%20down%20by%20discipline&f=false) (see footnotes 63 and 64) but I found the corresponding [pre-print](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3664).

The needed data set has to include all published articles, the publication year, the information of the access state on article level (gold/green) and a consistent classification.

One could start by using [google scholar](http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0013636) or the [Thomson Reuters list](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3664) to collect all published articles and [repositories](http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0013636) or a [web trawler](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3664) to find corresponding green open access versions. One could also use a data collector as [BASE](https://www.base-search.net/about/en/about_sources.php?menu=2) (Bielefeld Academic Search Engine). BASE offers [browsing using the DDC](https://www.base-search.net/Browse/Dewey) which should help to identify the publications of the different disciplines, if one has no access to the Thomson Reuters list. Additionally, each article has an access state. The access state of an article can also be collected from [oaDOI](https://oadoi.org).

There are definitely several ways to get the needed information. Unfortunately, it seems that no one has done this work recently.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the research team at Open University.  Contact [Petr Knoth](http://people.kmi.open.ac.uk/petr/#projects).  This is what he and his team are working on.

'It is now the world¹s largest collection of Open
Access research papers and we are working to popularise it as a dataset
for text-mining.'